# libcurl - unable to download a file

Tags: c++, curl, download, libcurl

I'm working on a program which will download lyrics from sites like AZLyrics. I'm using libcurl.
 
It's my code

lyricsDownloader.cpp

```
#include "lyricsDownloader.h"
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#define DEBUG 1

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


size_t lyricsDownloader::write_data_to_var(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) // this function is a static member function
{
    ostringstream * stream = (ostringstream*) userdata;
    size_t count = size * nmemb;
    stream->write(ptr, count);
    return count;
}


string AZLyricsDownloader::toProviderCode() const
{ /*this creates an url*/ }

CURLcode AZLyricsDownloader::download()
{
    CURL * handle;
    CURLcode err;
    ostringstream buff;
    handle = curl_easy_init();
    if (! handle) return static_cast<CURLcode>(-1);
    // set verbose if debug on
    curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, DEBUG );
    curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_URL, toProviderCode().c_str() ); // set the download url to the generated one
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buff);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &AZLyricsDownloader::write_data_to_var);
    err = curl_easy_perform(handle); // The segfault should be somewhere here - after calling the function but before it ends
    cerr << "cleanup\n";
    curl_easy_cleanup(handle);

    // copy the contents to text variable
    lyrics = buff.str();
    return err;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <iostream>
#include "lyricsDownloader.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        AZLyricsDownloader dl(argv[1], argv[2]);
        dl.perform();
        QTextEdit qtexted(QString::fromStdString(dl.lyrics));
        cout << qPrintable(qtexted.toPlainText());
        return 0;
}
```

When running

```
./maelyrica Anthrax Madhouse
```

I'm getting this logged from curl

```
* About to connect() to azlyrics.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 174.142.163.250... * connected
* Connected to azlyrics.com (174.142.163.250) port 80 (#0)
> GET /lyrics/anthrax/madhouse.html HTTP/1.1
Host: azlyrics.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.0.12
< Date: Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:59:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/anthrax/madhouse.html
< 
Segmentation fault
```

Strangely, the file is there. The same error is displayed when there's no such page (redirect to azlyrics.com mainpage)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I made the function for writing data static, but this changes nothing.
Even wget seems to have problems

```
$ wget http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/anthrax/madhouse.html
--2012-07-06 10:36:05--  http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/anthrax/madhouse.html
Resolving www.azlyrics.com... 174.142.163.250
Connecting to www.azlyrics.com|174.142.163.250|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

Why does opening the page in a browser work and wget/curl not?

EDIT2: After adding this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

And making the function static everything's OK.

Comment: Before posting here, you should be able to narrow down where the seg-fault is coming from, and reduce the code to the relevant section.  Posting all your code with a "What am I doing wrong?" is not the right way to go.    Running your code in a debugger like gdb, should make finding the location of the seg-fault extremely easy.

Comment: Hard to sift through a "wall of code" a short self contained compiling example is best to focus your question on a specific problem you're having. Also by coming up with a more narrow example you can sometimes solve the problem yourself in the process!

Comment: OK, sorry, I'm quite new here :)
I reduced the number of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
    curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,&AZLyricsDownloader::write_data_to_var);
```

and the following quote from the [documentation from libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html)

> There's basically only one thing to keep in mind when using C++
>   instead of C when interfacing libcurl:
>
> The callbacks CANNOT be non-static class member functions
>
> Example C++ code:
>
> class AClass {   static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,   void* ourpointer)   {  /* do what you want with the data */   }  }

could be the source of your problem as your function is not a static member. Even if not you are breaking this rule.

This may not solve your problem but given the amount of code you have posted in your example, that was the first thing that immediately came to mind and it is worth changing this as recommended by libcurl. If it does not solve your problem I would suggest identifying the error you are getting in more detail so that you can pose a more specific question next time (with a lot less code displayed).

Comment: @marmistrz oh well - it is still a good thing to do as libcurl say. may prevent other problems in future.

Comment: EDIT: The problem was indeed the non-static function combined with libcurl not following redirects. Thanks!