# Sending and receiving strings over http via curl

Tags: c++, c, http, curl, client-server

I have a situation where my program on a server (windows machine) outputs some strings. I need to send those strings from the server to the client via HTTP using curl. Once sent I am to receive the data on the client side as string, decode it and perform subsequent actions.
I already achieved this functionality using `C Sockets` using berkely API as I had familiarity with that. But for some reason I am not allowed to use a program of my own.
I poked around and seems CURL can be my solution. However I am very new to curl and cant seem to figure out how to achieve this functionality. On the Client side I found this to be useful may be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I understand that you have to use the write back functions to receive data ?
Also on the client side I need to develop a program using curl that whenever the server sends over a string, it should receive it and decode it. Any pointers to tutorials related to the specific problems will be highly appreciated. Or if someone has already tried this I'll highly appreciate any help here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example code from their site. It details how to get your response data written to a region of memory rather than a file:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

also take a look at the generic tutorial on the curl website:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html

one final thing to consider, if using C++ you need to make sure your callbacks are not non static member functions (see here [libcurl - unable to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349101/libcurl-unable-to-download-a-file/11349306#11349306))

This should get you started at least.